# Whole layout going up with androidWindowSofInputMode="adjustResize"

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a app, where my fragment layout has three part- header, content part(ListView),
footer(a EditText).
I wanted to take the editText to up as the keyboard is opened. So, I set androidWindowSofInputMode="adjustResize" But it is resizing complete layout, Besides, just resizing the ListView, Since, there is a wallpaper on my parent view, and it gets shrinked due to complete layout getting resized.

I see in apps like WhatsApp and hike that only EditText goes up and the chat wallpaper remains  as it is(not shrinked).

Answer (score 0):

Use adjustPan instead. It does exactly that.

Comment: I already tried, But it is taking my header view up too....My header view gets hidden. I want it to remain there.

Comment: Well, you didn't say that in your question. Anyway, if there's not enough room to show both header and footer, the header will be pushed up. Why is that so bad anyway? It's more important to see the EditText. The only other option would be to hide the content part when the keyboard is opened.